# Listing page redirect issue in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm working on php, I have fetched all the data from database and and I have to show listing the page,I have to show all the dynamic date in listing page & I'm fetching all the data from database but how to redirect and show listing page, how I tried this I'm not getting please check my code and help me.

Here my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  test" data-idtest="Diabetes">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="box_cat_home">
                        <i class="icon-info-4"></i>
                        <img src="assets/img/icon_cat_3.svg" width="60" height="60" alt="">
                        <h3>Diabetes</h3>
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li><strong>124</strong>Doctors</li>
                        <!-- <li><strong>60</strong>Clinics</li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

my Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.test').click(function (){
            var id = $(this).data('idtest') ; 
            alert(id);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url : "speciallist.php",
        data    : {id:id },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
        }
      });
      })
    });
</script>
```

Here my PHP code:

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'mysql';
$dbName = 'fre';
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

$id =$_REQUEST['id'];

      $men ="select * from tbl_users where doctor_speciality='$id'";
      $men_result=$db->query($men);
      $projects=array();
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($men_result)){ 
      $projects[] = $row;
  }
?>
```

dynamic Listing page: speciallist.php

```
<div class="col-lg-12 list-items">
                    <?php foreach($projects as $row){
                    $userId = $row['userId'];?>
                <div class="strip_list wow fadeIn">
                    <a href="#0" class="wish_bt"></a>
                    <figure>
                        <!-- <a href="detail.php"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/565x565.jpg" alt=""></a> -->
                        <a href="detail.php?userId=<?php echo $userId;?>"><img src="<?php echo "admin/uploads"."/".$row['doctor_image']; ?>"</a>
                    </figure>
                    <a href="detail.php?userId=<?php echo $userId;?>"><h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3></a>
                    <p><!-- Doctor Education : --> <?php echo $row['doctor_education']; ?>,<?php echo $row['doctor_speciality']; ?></p>
                    <p> 9 years experience</p>
                    <p>Gynecologist/Obstetrician</p>
                    <!-- <p> Doctor Speciality : <?php echo $row['doctor_speciality']; ?></p> -->
                    <!-- <p><?php echo $row['doctor_profile']; ?></p> -->
                    <p><!--  Mobile : --> <?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></p>
                    <!-- <p><?php echo $row['doctor_profile']; ?></p> -->
                    <!-- <p>Dr. Mr is a Senior Endodontist, specializes in Smile Designing, Single Visit Root Canal Treatments, Implants, Cosmetic Dentistry.</p> -->
                    <div class="sideleft">
                        <p>Clinic Name:<?php echo $row['clinic_name']; ?></p>
                        <p>Clinic Address:<?php echo $row['clinic_address']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>MON-SAT 9:00 AM - 9:30 PM</li>
                        <li><a href="detail.php?userId=<?php echo $userId;?>">Book now</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Okay, and what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Hi CodeThing , i'm not getting any issue sir, all the data is coming from database i want to show listing page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the 'PHP Code' to the top of specialist.php and change your javascript code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.test').click(function (){
        var id = $(this).data('idtest') ; 
        alert(id);
        document.location = "speciallist.php?id=" + id;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i bet you have understand everything and learn a lot today. lucky you :)

Comment: @websynod: its a good practice to explain where is the error on the OP's code, how it can be solved and why you are giving that solution so others can understand and in the future can improve the answers and be helpful to the community.

Comment: At last comment your code so the op know what and why. Thanks for understanding.